# Using winAPI to open mspaint

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to open mspaint using winAPI. For some reason, the window doesn't shown and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;


    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = true;

    CreateProcessA("mspaint.exe", (LPSTR)"mspaint.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What if you replace the second argument to `CreateProcessA` with `NULL`? AFAIK, the way you're doing things now will be interpreted as if you wanted to run `mspaint.exe mspaint.exe` (i.e. start `mspaint.exe` and open an image named `mspaint.exe`).

Comment: You are not checking for errors. What does `CreateProcessA` return and what does `GetLastError()` report?

Comment: @Michael You're right (and that cast is UB), and `mspaint` doesn't like that if you do it from the command line, but that's not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Specify the absolute path to mspaint.

Comment: @ark1974 Why is that a good solution?  Suppose you don't know where it is (or if it moves between different versions of Windows, say).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the lack of error checking in your code (and the illegal cast), if you refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), you will see that:

> The function will not use the search path.

So, unless `mspaint.exe` happens to reside in the current directory (which is most unlikely) then `CreateProcess` won't find it.

The best solution is to use [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea), something along these lines (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = ShellExecuteA (NULL, "open", "mspaint.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Like `CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute` doesn't wait for the launched process to complete before returning.  If you want to do that, you can use [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) passing the SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS flag and then wait on the process handle returned before finally closing it (in the same way you are doing now).